# KeyboardAwareScrollView and KeyboardAvoidingView Both just compress the inputs together and don't move anything else on the screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an app that I am working on and am having trouble with the android styling.  Everything looked fine on iOS but then when I used it on an android emulator the inputs were squished towards the top and all of the text was overlapping.  So I'm trying to figure out how to use the KeyboardAwareScrollView or the KeyboardAvoidingView to either move absolutely everything on the page up or at least move the content under the header up and under the header so that you can still see the input.  Here are some screen shots to show what is currently happening.

The screen when inputs are not focused on:

[image]

The Screen when an input is focused on:

[image]

Here is my screen's code.  You can see by the commented out sections that I also tried placing these keyboard aware views on almost the very outside of my screen in an attempt to move the entire screen's content.  Instead, it continued to behave in the same way.

```
  return (
    <SafeAreaView edges={['top']} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary }}>
    <SafeAreaView edges={['left', 'right', 'bottom']} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: theme.colors['Surface'] }}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor={theme.colors.primary} />
      {/* <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={{ width: '100%', height: Dimensions.get('window').height, backgroundColor: theme.colors.Background, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}
          behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "padding"}
          contentContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
          enabled={true}
          keyboardVerticalOffset={-120}
        > */}
      {/* <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        extraHeight={0}
        enableOnAndroid={true}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ height: Dimensions.get('window').height }}
      > */}
      <ScreenContainer hasSafeArea={false} scrollable={false}>
          <View style={[styles.topBlueContainer, { backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary, position: 'absolute', zIndex: 99 }]}>
            {/* Logo */}
            <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
              <View style={styles.Viewfe3a5f26}>
                <Text
                  style={[styles.ConnectLogo, { color: theme.colors['Background'] }]}
                >
                  {'company'}
                </Text>

                <Text
                  style={[styles.WalletLogo, { color: theme.colors['Background'] }]}
                >
                  {'name'}
                </Text>

                <View style={styles.View63f8fbfb}>
                  <Icon
                    name={'AntDesign/trademark'}
                    size={8}
                    color={theme.colors['Background']}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>

            {/* header row */}
            <View style={[styles.headerRow, {}]}>
              <Touchable
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('PortfolioDetailsScreen');
                }}
                style={[styles.backArrowBtnContainer, {}]}
              >
                <Icon
                    name={'AntDesign/left'}
                    size={36}
                    color={theme.colors['Background']}
                />
              </Touchable>

              <View style={[styles.currencyTitleContainer, {}]}>
                <Text style={[styles.currencyTitleText, { color: theme.colors['Background'] }]}> SEND {selectedToken.symbol}</Text>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.backArrowBtnContainer} />
            </View>
          </View>

          {/* Page Content */}
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            extraScrollHeight={-220}
            style={[
                styles.contentContainer,
                {
                  height: '100%',
                  paddingTop: 120,
                }
            ]}
            contentContainerStyle={
              {
                alignItems: 'center',
                flex: 1
              }
            }
            resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            enableOnAndroid={true}
            viewIsInsideTabBar={true}
          >


              {/* Total Amnt Container */}
              <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '25%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 56, fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_600SemiBold', textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: -10 }}>{selectedToken.balance.toString().slice(0, 10)}</Text>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_400Regular', textAlign: 'center', color: '#979797' }}>Current Balance</Text>
              </View>

              {/* Amnt To Send Container */}
              <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '25%' }}>
                  <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '50%', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <TextInput
                    onChangeText={newTextInputValue => {
                      try {
                        if (newTextInputValue) {
                          if (newTextInputValue === '.') {
                            setAmountToSend('0.');
                          } else if (parseFloat(newTextInputValue) <= parseFloat(selectedToken.balance)) {
                            setAmountToSend(newTextInputValue);
                          } else {
                            Alert.alert('Not Enough Funds', reachedMaxButtons);
                          }
                        } else {
                          setAmountToSend(newTextInputValue);
                        }
                      } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                      }
                    }}
                    style={[
                      styles.amountInput,
                      { borderColor: theme.colors.divider },
                    ]}
                    placeholder={'0.00'}
                    value={amountToSend}
                    editable={true}
                    placeholderTextColor={theme.colors['Medium']}
                    keyboardType={'decimal-pad'}
                  />
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginTop: 10 }}>
                      <View style={{ width: 100 }}/>
                      <View>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_400Regular', textAlign: 'center', color: '#979797' }}>Amount</Text>
                      </View>
                      <Touchable
                        style={{
                          width: 100,
                          height: 30,
                          backgroundColor: theme.colors['Background'],
                          borderWidth: 1,
                          borderRadius: 23,
                          borderColor: '#347AF0',
                          alignItems: 'center',
                          justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {
                          setAmountToSend(selectedToken.balance.toString());
                        }}
                      >
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_600SemiBold', color: '#347AF0' }}>Max</Text>
                      </Touchable>
                  </View>
              </View>

              {/* Address Container */}
              <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '25%' }}>
                  <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '50%', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                      <TextInput
                      style={styles.addressInput}
                      placeholder={'0x43452...'}
                      placeholderTextColor={theme.colors['Medium']}
                      editable={true}
                      value={addressToSendTo}
                      onChangeText={newAddressValue => {
                          try {
                          setAddressToSendTo(newAddressValue);
                          } catch (err) {
                          console.error(err);
                          }
                      }}
                      />
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'flex-start', marginTop: 10 }}>
                      <View style={{ width: 100 }}/>
                      <View>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_400Regular', textAlign: 'center', color: '#979797' }}>Recipient</Text>
                      </View>
                      <Touchable
                        style={{
                          width: 100,
                          height: 30,
                          backgroundColor: theme.colors['Background'],
                          borderWidth: 1,
                          borderRadius: 23,
                          borderColor: '#347AF0',
                          alignItems: 'center',
                          justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}

                        onPress={() => {
                          navigation.navigate('CodeScannerScreen', { 'screen': 'SendTokenUpdatedScreen' });
                        }}
                      >
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_600SemiBold', color: '#347AF0' }}>Scan QR</Text>
                      </Touchable>
                  </View>
              </View>

            {/* Next Btn Container */}
            <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '25%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}>
                <Button
                  title={'Next'}
                  style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    maxWidth: 300,
                    height: 46,
                    fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_600SemiBold',
                    fontSize: 19,
                    color: theme.colors['Background'],
                    borderRadius: 23,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => {
                    console.log('amount', amountToSend)
                    console.log('amount there: ', amountToSend === '')
                    navigation.navigate('ConfirmSendTokenScreen', {
                      'amountToSend': amountToSend,
                      'addressToSendTo': addressToSendTo,
                      'selectedToken': selectedToken,
                    });
                  }}
                  disabled={addressToSendTo === '' || amountToSend === ''}
                />
            </View>
          </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      </ScreenContainer>
      {/* </KeyboardAvoidingView> */}
      {/* </KeyboardAwareScrollView> */}
    </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logoContainer: {
    paddingLeft: 15,
  },
  Viewfe3a5f26: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  WalletLogo: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    fontSize: 28,
    fontFamily: 'ProximaNova-Bold'
  },
  ConnectLogo: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    fontSize: 28,
    paddingRight: 5,
    fontFamily: 'ProximaNova-Regular'
  },
  View63f8fbfb: {
    paddingTop: 5,
  },
  topBlueContainer: {
    height: 120,
    width: '100%'
  },
  headerRow: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  backArrowBtnContainer: {
    paddingLeft: 12,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '15%',
  },
  currencyTitleContainer: {
    width: 200,
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '70%'
  },
  currencyTitleText: {
    fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_700Bold',
    fontSize: 36
  },
  contentContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
  },
  amountInput: {
    fontSize: 56,
    width: '100%',
    height: 56,
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_600SemiBold',
  },
  amountLabel: {
    fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_400Regular',
    color: '#979797',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  scanQRBtn: {
    width: 100,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 23,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  addressInput: {
    fontSize: 56,
    width: '100%',
    height: 56,
    marginTop: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_600SemiBold',
    borderColor: '#CFD2D8'
  },
  sendData: {
    fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_400Regular',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  splitContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '50%',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  sendCurrencyBtn: {
    width: 300,
    fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_600SemiBold',
    fontSize: 19,
    height: 46,
    borderRadius: 25,
    marginBottom: 20
  },
});
```

Can anyone help me either move the current balance section and the appropriate input up and out of the way or move the entire screen's content up and out of the way just up to where the focused input is just above the keyboard?